# Background colour is not supported (IOS) flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, html-to-pdf

CSS Background colour not supported while converting html to pdf.
I have used flutter_html_to_pdf library.

Flutter version: 3.10.6
Mac OS version: 13.5
Device OS Version: 16.6
Device: Iphone 12

https://github.com/Afur/flutter_html_to_pdf/issues/75

I tried with older version of flutter.